# Android upgrade possible for every device?

Tags: android

Is it possible for every Android mobile to be upgraded to its latest version or are there any limitations?

I have seen ad-tags for many mobile devices saying "Upgradeable to 2.2", or "Upgradeable to 2.1". Isn't upgrading a mobile OS just like upgrading a desktop OS?

Comment: sohuld be moved to http://android.stackexchange.com/ as it is not a programming related question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the manufacturer.  I have an HTC Desire and I don't believe there are any plans to upgrade that to Android 2.3, however the HTC Desire HD has.  I could install an unofficial 'port' of Android 2.3, but it wouldn't be a reliable as the official.

Bottom line is, yes I believe it is possible, but it won't always happen.

Comment: Please consider hardware requirements! If the internal memory is not enough, you can't update. Even an unofficial "port" like cyanogenmod. Btw: cyanogenmod has a high quality, if the desire really stays on 2.2 I would recommend to use it...

Comment: @WarrenFaith:  Good point about the memory.  I have tried previous unofficial ports and have been disappointed so I try and stay with official ports whenever possible, however if HTC don't do a 2.3 then I will definitely try an unofficial one.